# Create a separate column in Pandas dataframe based on a condition

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column named as 'Finding Ageing in Days' with integers ranging from 0 till 100. I want to create a new column called "Ageing" that contains values based on 3 conditions: none (if Finding Ageing in Days=0), '=1 day' (if Finding Ageing in Days=1), '>1 day' (if Finding Ageing in Days>1). I tried If loops and apply but these did not work. Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not scalable but easy solution:

```py
df.loc[df['Finding Ageing in Days'].eq(0), "Ageing"] = None
df.loc[df['Finding Ageing in Days'].eq(1), "Ageing"] = '=1 day'
df.loc[df['Finding Ageing in Days'].gt(1), "Ageing"] = '>1 day'
```